# How to download a XML file http?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, http, url, web

I tried, 2 methods to download an XML file:

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

url = "http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/download_file.jsp?filePath=/resources/msigdb/6.2/msigdb_v6.2.xml"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open("lol.xml", "wb") as handle:
    for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
        handle.write(data)
```

and the second one:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()
print(data)
```

The URL is redirected to:

```
response.url
u'https://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/login.jsp;jsessionid=2544FF431CB094FBBA80451EDD3A0411'
```

It turns out, that I only download the html file and not the xml file, an code snippet of the output:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <base href="http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <meta name="verify-v1" content="/23Jlayki9tnRqU7DcCYrbFI7zPmHJ3HfeZltM6mK5Q=" />
    <title>GSEA | Login</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

How to download the XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
file.write(response.content)
```

instead last two lines in your first method.
The problem might be the fact that you can not download the file directly from this link (requires login):

```
url = "http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/download_file.jsp?filePath=/resources/msigdb/6.2/msigdb_v6.2.xml"
```

Comment: It does not work. Do you mean `handle.write(response.content)?

Comment: Yess
handle.write(response.content)